# How to fix live application with facebook login not working in xamarin forms?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Any one know how to fix facebook login not working on live product in xamarin forms ? I already turn on the toggle button on facebook live product.
[I follow and implement this blog](http://www.xamboy.com/2018/03/26/facebook-client-plugin-for-xamarin/)

in my local computer facebook login is work but when i make it live it show to popup dialog to continue with facebook but not go to home page but this function is working in local.

Comment: Please post relevant code with your question and read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: Hi @FabriBertani please see the question above again i already update. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.